# Loading and processing five files at a time from a directory containing many, many files

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I have 3000 files (for example: aa101.csv, aa108.csv, aa120.csv, ...) and I need to process them. I need to load five files from a folder, process them, and export them to new list in Excel. Then I need to take another five files from the same folder and process them, and so on.

I tried

```
printer[n_] := 
  Module[{file = n},

    calculation...
    ...

    Export[name <> ".xlsx", {data}, "Data"];
  ]

printer[Import["E:\\mathematica\\a\\*", "text"]];
```

But `printer` loads all files from the specified folder.

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Function `printer` take name of the file or data from file?

Comment: This function takes data from files

Answer (score 2):

This somewhat depends on your specific file names, desired target filename and location, the details of procedure etc. There would be a number of approaches. I post this for motivation.

In the following I assume:

- all the files for processing are in the same directory (and number  0 Mod 5)
- they have a sequential nomenclature that will be preserved
- they are .csv
- the target directory is the same folder

and will use "file001.xlsx","file002.xlsx",...etc and the procedure is a function `fun`:

```
SetDirectory["your directory"]
(* get file names and check in desired order*)
fn=FileNames["*.csv"]
(* partition into desired set of 5 *)
pfn=Partition[fn,5];
(* procedure on 5 files *)
proc=Map[Function[x,fun[Import[#,"Text"]&/@x]],pfn]
(*this produces the processed files in a list*)
(*exporting list*)
MapIndexed[Export[
 "file" <> IntegerString[First@#2, 10, 3] <> ".xlsx",#1,"Data"] &, proc]
```

Whatever approach you ultimately use I suggest testing on small test set to confirm desired outcome.

Comment: There is problem with function fun, it doesnt load data from files.     Output:     Import::chtype: First argument #1 is not a valid file, directory, or URL specification. >>        {fun[{$Failed["file001.csv"], $Failed["file002.csv"], $Failed["file003.csv"], $Failed["file004.csv"], $Failed["file005.csv"]}], 
 fun[{$Failed["file006.csv"], $Failed["file007.csv"], $Failed["TS2404_T1-8042.csv"], $Failed["TS2406_T1-806new2.csv"], $Failed[
    "TS5620_T1-1484new.csv"]}]}

Comment: @Lefl as I commented `fun` was just the name I used for the user defined function/procedure hence in this code it is "dummy code" for insert whatever your procedure. I explicitly listed the point of the post was motivation. There was insufficient information in the question for a "solution".

Comment: I can´t give my calculations in "fun" because I can´t load data from files. Do you know please what I have to change to load data from files?

Comment: @Lefl if you just wish to get import the data then run your procedure: `imported=Map[Function[x,Import[#,"Text"]/@x],pfn]` should produce a list, each element will 5 imported csv files. Then you can run your procedure.

Comment: @Lefl 1. Have you set directory to file location? 2. Can you give a short list of first few elements of `pfn`

Comment: yes I set directory to files: out1: E:\mathematica\a   out2: {"file001.csv", "file002.csv", "file003.csv", "file004.csv", \
"file005.csv", "file006.csv", "file007.csv", "file008.csv", \
"file009.csv", "file010.csv"}  out 3=out of pfn: {{"file001.csv", "file002.csv", "file003.csv", "file004.csv", 
  "file005.csv"}, {"file006.csv", "file007.csv", "file008.csv", 
  "file009.csv", "file010.csv"}}   But it is still problem: Import::chtype: First argument #1 is not a valid file, directory, or URL specification.

Comment: @Lefl ok...I only added "Text" based on your post...final suggestion: `imported=Map[Function[x,Import[#]/@x],pfn]`

Comment: It still doesnt work :(

Comment: @Lefl I had a syntax error: corrected is `imported=Map[Function[x,Import[#]&/@x],pfn]`. My sincerest apologies. As a moderator has suggested you could move to a chat room if this fails. Unfortunately, I am on call and have little time to devote. Perhaps in chat room other more expert users will offer assistance. Again sorry about omitting &